# Difference between quorom and zookeeper ensemble

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

Can anybody explain me the difference ..really confused
I am new to DFS and zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have high availability in zookeeper server you use multiple zookeeper servers to create an ensemble. Basically zookeeper has master-slave architecture. In an ensemble there will be one master and rest will be the slaves. If the master fails one of the slaves will act as a master.

The sequence in which a master is assigned is called as quorum. When you create an ensemble, zookeeper internally creates a sequence ID for the slave severs. When the main master fails it will check the next sequence ID to create a new master. This concept of quorum also used while creating nodes in zookeeper.

[difference between ensemble and quorum in zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174622/difference-between-ensemble-and-quorum-in-zookeeper/25216386#25216386)